# Freebase query to return rdf:resource uri

Tags: freebase

I am trying to get the freebase resource uri rather than the literal for a persons place of birth.

My get looks like this...

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={%22/people/person/place_of_birth%22:null,%22id%22:%22/en/bob_dylan%22}
```

which returns this result...

```
{
"result": {
"/people/person/place_of_birth": "Duluth", 
"id": "/en/bob_dylan"
}
}
```

is it possible to alter the get params to return the rdf:resource uri?

```
<fb:people.person.place_of_birth rdf:resource="http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/en.tilden"/>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you cut and paste from two different examples?  Tilden and Duluth aren't the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your query to

```
{
  "id": "/en/bob_dylan",
  "/people/person/place_of_birth": {
    "id": null
  }
}​
```

will mean you get back `/en/duluth` rather than the name "Duluth". With the new Freebase API hosted at googleapis.com, you'll probably get `/m/0h1k6` rather than `/en/duluth`; however these are equivalent.

From there, moving to the RDF resource URI should be pretty easy. However, note that the Freebase team have deprecated the RDF URIs and have not formally committed to producing a like-for-like replacement, so you'll want to be careful before relying on this service.

Comment: Note that if you don't get back an MID, you should change the query to ask for it instead of an ID since that's what's recommended for use as the stable external identifier. http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0h1k6

Comment: Just to clarify, we've deprecated the /en IDs meaning that all the current /en IDs will continue to work but they will be de-emphasized in the Freebase UI and no new /en IDs will be created. The mappings between /en URIs and /m URIs are all available from sameas.org so you can move easily bewteen the two naming schemes.